# Append data table column to other data table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datatables

I have two data tables. The first one has multiple rows with the same "IPC" value but different "Subordination" value.  Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v37h.png)

The second data table has unique values of "IPC" (BBG IPC code) and "Subordination" (Seniority) like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acoQg.png)

I need to append to the second data table all the columns of the first datatable with matching IPC and Subordination (except IPC and Subordination columns already present with different column name).

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laWe5.png)

I'm a beginner with data table manipulation and i'm looking for a solution in C# with LINQ. Thank You for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("IPC", typeof(long));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Subordination", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Current SBR", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Forward SBR", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Probability", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Risk Category", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Restricted Message", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12345, "T4", "BB", "BB", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12345, "Senior", "BB", "BB", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12345, "T2", "CC", "CC", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 54321, "T1", "AA", "AA", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 54321, "T2", "AA", "AA", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12345, "T3", "BB", "BB", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 54321, "Senior", "AAA", "AAA", "High", "R1", "Something", "Something" });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Sector", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("BBG IPC", typeof(long));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Analyst", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Issuer Group", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Seniority", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Mkt Value", typeof(long));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Nom Value", typeof(long));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Issue Group Rating", typeof(string));

            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agency", 12345, "RIZ", "Cores", "Senior", "50256", 124515, "BB" });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Car", 54321, "MUS", "Cores", "T2", "515155", 15215231, "AA" });

            var joins = dt1.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(t1 => dt2.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(t2 => (t1.Field<long>("IPC") == t2.Field<long>("BBG IPC")) && (t1.Field<string>("Subordination") == t2.Field<string>("Seniority")))
                .Select(t2 => new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 }
            )).ToList();

            DataTable dt3 = dt2.Clone();
            dt3.Columns.Add("Current SBR", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Forward SBR", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Probability", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Risk Category", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Restricted Message", typeof(string));

            foreach (var join in joins)
            {
                DataRow row = dt3.Rows.Add();
                row.ItemArray = join.t2.ItemArray;
                row["Current SBR"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Current SBR");
                row["Forward SBR"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Forward SBR");
                row["Probability"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Probability");
                row["Risk Category"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Risk Category");
                row["Comment"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Comment");
                row["Restricted Message"] = join.t1.Field<string>("Restricted Message");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated code so I;m not adding columns to second original table.